# gtk python lists strings gettiing text from combo box

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/dCL7Nt8K

I am working in python and I am thinking it is a list or dictionary that I am workig with but I am using the program to fetch what types of videos can be retrieved.

I have it to where it will get the information and put it into the combobox but I want to be able to compare the information and when I print the `get_active_text` I get a 0,1,2,3, etc. based on the position of the item in the combobox, which doesn't bother me a ton, I just want to compare if the Item that is in the combobox and see if it is `==` to N.

I hope this makes sense. I am using a 3rd party library which works ideally for the situation.

Can you let me know what it is that I am working with? Are they called tuples?

```
def cb_changed(w): passw = w.get_active()



    liststore1 = gtk.ListStore(str)
    liststore2 = gtk.ListStore(str)
    liststore3 = gtk.ListStore(str)
    liststore4 = gtk.ListStore(str)
    liststore5 = gtk.ListStore(str)
    liststore6 = gtk.ListStore(str)

    def combo1_text(widget):
            yt = YouTube()
            yt.url = Conviare.entry1.get_text()
            videolist = yt.videos
            for videos in yt.videos:
                    Conviare.liststore1.append([videos])
            return videolist
```

Sorry I ma trying to make as much sense of this as possible.
for a simple Pytube documentation I one can look at this http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytube/ . It's really really simple(try it). I took what he is pprinting and put into the combo box, I am using the liststore1 to hold this list.
I just want to be able to some how download so that the user can select a combobox and have it download what the user wants. The pastebin is the source code if needed.

Comment: Please include your code *here*, reduced to a small reproduceable sample of what you are talking about.

Comment: And no, you are not making much sense so far to me, so far. Sorry! You need to reduce this to a much smaller example of what you don't understand.

Comment: The pastebin has expired so we cannot see the complete code.

Comment: There is an answer for this already . I asked this question many many years ago and I probably don't have the source code any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not working with primitive Python data types such as lists or tuples, you are working with GTK widgets wrapped by PyGTK into objects accessible from Python. For more details, refer to the [reference documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkcombobox.html) and [tutorial](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-ComboBoxAndComboboxEntry.html) of `gtk.ComboBox`.

Comment: Thanks I found the answer! filetype1 = myclass.combo1.get_active_text()

Comment: @user1935655 You're welcome. From your question it seemed that you were aware of `get_active_text`, but that for some reason it didn't work as you expected. In the future when asking questions, be sure to limit the scope of the question as much as you can, so that it can be reasonably and concretely answered.